# How to have a role selection menu (py_cord slash commands)

Tags: python, discord.py, pycord

Hello so I'm working on a discord bot and I'm trying to add selecting a role as an argument for this command. It should look something like

[image]

Here's my code right now

```
@bot.slash_command(name = "setrankroles",guild_ids = [898725831164178442])
async def setroles(ctx,
    role: Option(discord.Role,"What role are you assigning?"),
    rank: Option(str, "What rank goes with that role?", choices=valid_ranks),
    ):
```

It produces this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/maximummaxx/Documents/Coding/Python/Valorant_dc/main.py", line 205, in <module>
    role: Option(discord.Role,"What role are you assigning?"),
  File "/home/maximummaxx/Documents/Coding/Python/Valorant_dc/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/commands/commands.py", line 510, in __init__
    to_assign = input_type() if isinstance(input_type, type) else input_type
TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required keyword-only arguments: 'guild', 'state', and 'data'
```

Thanks

Comment: Image is not uploaded properly - cannot see.

Comment: loads fine for me. Try this https://i.imgur.com/5oBNq5R.png

Comment: What is valid_ranks set as?

Comment: @Lloyd It’s a list of strings like [“Bronze”,”Silver”,”Daimond”]

Answer (score 1):

**First Problem**

`valid_ranks` is just a list of strings, but that is a invalid input.
Instead you need to have `OptionChoice`s in `valid_ranks`

Like so:

```py
from discord.commands import OptionChoice #  Don't forget to import OptionChoice

valid_ranks = [
    OptionChoice(name="Bronze", value="Bronze"), #  Value must be a string.
    OptionChoice(name="Silver", value="Silver"), #  Value must be a string.
    OptionChoice(name="Diamond", value="Diamond") #  Value must be a string.
]
```

Name is the option that will appear and `value` is the value assigned to it.
`value` can only be a string, but you can convert it later in the code.

**Second Problem**

You need to add a few arguments to the first Option.

Here is a example that should work.

```py
role: Option(
    discord.Role,
    name="role",
    description="What role are you assigning?",
    guild_ids=servers
)
```

**Final Product**

After you've finished all that. It should look something like this.

```py
valid_ranks = [
    OptionChoice(name="Bronze", value="Bronze"), #  Value must be a string.
    OptionChoice(name="Silver", value="Silver"), #  Value must be a string.
    OptionChoice(name="Diamond", value="Diamond") #  Value must be a string.
]


@client.slash_command(name="setrankroles", guild_ids=[898725831164178442])
async def setroles(
        ctx,
        role: Option(
            discord.Role,
            name="role",
            description="What role are you assigning?",
        ),
        rank: Option(str, "What rank goes with that role?", choices=valid_ranks),
):
```

Comment: The optionchoice stuff doesn't seem to be working, the role part is fine though.

Comment: Did you import the package with ```from discord.commands import OptionChoice``` @MaxwellWindland?

Comment: yup it is definitely imported. @Lloyd

Comment: @MaxwellWindlandDo you get any errors?

Comment: No, no errors @Lloyd

Answer (score 0):

Slash commands autocompletes in pycord are actually not that hard.

For built-ins like `Role`, your function would be something like this

```py
@commands.slash_command()
async def command(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    ....
```

similarly, for autocompletes of non-builtins you can use the `autocomplete` parameter for `Option`

```py
@commands.slash_command()
async def command(ctx, fruit: discord.Option(
    str,
    name="fruit"
    required=True,
    autocomplete=fruitAutoComplete
)
):
    ....
```

Notice the lack of parentheses on fruitAutoComplete, this is called a partial and basically means you're passing a reference to a function

The function `fruitAutoComplete()` would be implemented like so

```
def fruitAutoComplete(ctx: discord.AutocompleteContext):
    """Returns the list of fruit that start with what you've typed"""
    filtered = list(
        filter(
            lambda x: x.lower().startswith(
                ctx.value.lower()
            ),
            fruitList
        )
    )
    return filtered
```

Note that you'll have to define fruitList somewhere in the file where your autocomplete is defined.

This function chains a few built-ins together to filter for starting.

If you really wanted, you could use the `fuzzywuzzy` package to do fuzzy matching for text. Perhaps something like this.

```
def fruitAutoComplete(ctx: discord.AutocompleteContext):
    """Returns the list of fruit that start with what you've typed"""
    filtered = list(
        map(lambda x: x[0],
            process.extract(input,fruitList)
        )
    )
    return filtered
```

If you want to get really fancy with it, you could make a general autocomplete like this.

```
def generalAutoComplete(items, ctx: discord.AutocompleteContext):
    """Returns the list of fruit that start with what you've typed"""
    filtered = list(
        map(lambda x: x[0],
            process.extract(input,items)
        )
    )
    return filtered
```

To use this general function, you would pass it into your option like this

```py
@commands.slash_command()
async def command(ctx, fruit: discord.Option(
    str,
    name="fruit"
    required=True,
    autocomplete=generalAutoComplete(fruitList)
)
):
    ....
```

Here you're only passing one argument, returning a partial, but also giving you a reusable function for any sort of autocomplete you might need.